# Androidx RecycleView Not showing items with parse server

Tags: java, android, androidx

This is my adapter for recycle view

**CategoryAdapter Class**

```
public class CategoryRAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mcontext;
private List<Food> mData;
RequestOptions option;

public CategoryRAdapter(Context mcontext, List<Food> mData) {
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    this.mData = mData;

    option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.food_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Food current = mData.get(position);
    holder.tv_Name.setText(current.getName());
    holder.tv_Rating.setText(current.getRating());
    holder.tv_Descip.setText(current.getDescrip());
    holder.tv_Category.setText(current.getCateg());
    Glide.with(mcontext).load(mData.get(position).getImages()).apply(option).into(holder.img_Thumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_Name;
    TextView tv_Rating;
    TextView tv_Descip;
    TextView tv_Category;
    ImageView img_Thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv_Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        tv_Rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        tv_Descip = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        tv_Category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        img_Thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}
}
```

This is my model

**Food Class**

```
public class Food {
    String Name;
    String Images;
    String Descrip;
    String Rating;
    String Categ;

public Food() {
}

public Food(String name, String images, String descrip, String rating, String categ) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Images = images;
    this.Descrip = descrip;
    this.Rating = rating;
    this.Categ = categ;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImages() {
    return Images;
}

public void setImages(String images) {
    Images = images;
}

public String getDescrip() {
    return Descrip;
}

public void setDescrip(String descrip) {
    Descrip = descrip;
}

public String getRating() {
    return Rating;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    Rating = rating;
}

public String getCateg() {
    return Categ;
}

public void setCateg(String categ) {
    Categ = categ;
}
}
```

My mian activity

**CategoryActivity Class**

```
public class CategoriaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Food> dbObjects;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
private AlertDialog dialog;
TextView l_nombre,l_precio;
Button l_finalizar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_id);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    dbObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Category");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objList, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                for (ParseObject obj : objList) {
                    Food food = new Food();
                    food.setName(obj.getString("Name"));
                    food.setDescrip(obj.getString("Descrip"));
                    food.setRating(obj.getString("Rating"));
                    food.setCateg(obj.getString("Categ"));
                    food.setImages(obj.getString("Images"));
                    dbObjects.add(food);
                }
            } else {
                FancyToast.makeText(CategoriaActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.ERROR, true).show();
            }
        }
    });

    adapter = new CategoryRAdapter(this, dbObjects);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.shoppingFlot);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            carritopop();
        }
    });
}

private void carritopop() {
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pop_cart,null);
    l_finalizar = view.findViewById(R.id.l_finalizar);
    l_finalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pago();
        }
    });

    dialogBuilder.setView(view);
    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

private void pago() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CategoriaActivity.this, PagoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

I dont know whats wrong with the code, the recycle view aint working, it aint showing any items, i would really appreciate if someone could help me out and notice something wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your query done callback, this will notify the adapter that the list has changed. This is happening because when you set the adapter, the list was empty as the query was running in background. Once it completes, you have to tell the adapter that new data has been added to list:

```
if (e == null) {
    for (ParseObject obj : objList) {
          ...
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also, create your adapter before you send the query otherwise it may result in `NullPointerException` in case data is loaded before the next statement executes (highly unlikely but never hurts to be safe).

```
dbObjects = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new CategoryRAdapter(this, dbObjects);
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Category");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use RxJava2 to user asynchronous methods, it's awesome... And about the problem, maybe your data is not ready when you're already creating the adapter with the ArrayList.

Try to move the `recyclerView.setAdapter(`) to inside the `FindCallback` after create the Food Objects.